# Query to get report name, reports first and last run time and date, how often it was run and method of delivery (email or locations)

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, reportingservices-2005

I am new to sql server.

I have been trying to write a query to get report name, reports first and last run time and date, scheduled by ,how often it was run and method of delivery (email or locations) for SQL Server 2005.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1846/how-to-easily-identify-a-scheduled-sql-server-reporting-services-report/)

```
 SELECT

'EXEC ReportServer.dbo.AddEvent @EventType=''TimedSubscription'',    @EventData=''' 
+ CAST(a.SubscriptionID AS VARCHAR(40)) + '''' AS ReportCommand

        , b.name AS JobName

        , a.SubscriptionID

        , e.name

        , e.path

        , d.description

        , laststatus

        , eventtype

        , LastRunTime

        , date_created

        , date_modified

FROM ReportServer.dbo.ReportSchedule a JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs b

        ON a.ScheduleID = b.name

        JOIN ReportServer.dbo.ReportSchedule c

        ON b.name = c.ScheduleID

        JOIN ReportServer.dbo.Subscriptions d

        ON c.SubscriptionID = d.SubscriptionID

        JOIN ReportServer.dbo.Catalog e

        ON d.report_oid = e.itemid

WHERE e.name = 'Sales_Report'
```